# Regex match xml attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, regex, parsing

I want to get the integer value of this xml attribute `limit=\"25\"`

I tried this :`Match match = Regex.Match(response.Content, "(?<=limit=))\\d+");`
gives me an error : "too many )'s.

and this : `Match match = Regex.Match(response.Content, @"limit=([0-9])$"`
this returns nothing, the match is not successful

From this xml:

```
<issues type="array" limit="25" total_count="251" offset="0">
<issue>
<id>4317</id>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an xml parser?

Comment: Because my program receives a string formatted as xml

Comment: @ConradC dont use `REGEX` please...

Comment: @ConradC `a string formatted as xml` best case to use a real xml parser.

Comment: @ConradC - how does your program receiving a string formatted as xml preclude the use of an XML parser?

Comment: @ConradC What you have posted is not a valid xml. You won't get a good answer if you don't ask a good question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's better to use

string TheStringNeededToBeParsed = "... the xml ";

TheStringNeededToBeParsed .IndexOf(...

Answer (score 1):

Your first regex has too many )s in it. Count them.

Your second is failing because of the quotation marks around the attribute value. Try `"limit=\"([0-9])\"$"` instead.

Lots of people will tell you to use an XML parser instead. I would strongly recommend that if you're doing anything more than very minor extraction of data from well-known XML, because XML itself isn't parseable with regular expressions.

Comment: The second is also failing because there's more than one digit. Try `"limit=\"([0-9]+)\"$"` or `"limit=\"(\d+)\"$"`.

Answer (score 1):

`Regex` can be used for parsing XML since it is **strict** with its format but it is not **recommended** to use it

Use `LINQ2XML`

```
XElement doc=XElement.Parse(response.Content);       
var value=doc.Attribute("limit").Value;
```

**OR**

```
var value=Regex.Match(response.Content, @"limit=""(\d+)""",RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not want a collection of child elements, The element is the first one in the xml.

<issues type="array" limit="25" total_count="251" offset="0">
<issue>
<id>4317</id>

Comment: @ConradC sorry for the late reply..check out the edit

Comment: Its fine, but you code does not work, it returns an empty string.
I used indexof to get the indexes of limit and of the " "  then I get the value with substring.
the attribue is this `limit=\"25\"` there are \  backslashes

Comment: @ConradC - The regex between the quotes in the second example here needs to be: limit=""(\d+)""

Comment: @FrancisGagnon thxx..for that

Comment: @ConradC if this ans has solved your problem..u can accept it